# Find the gain \$K\$ at a point of given rootlocus?

Tags: control, control-system, homework

### [image]

From the given information i can write the transfer function as

$$G(s)=\frac{384}{s(s+4)(s+8)}$$
now get the value of \$K\$ at \$s=-1.5+j1.5\$ which is in root locus the generalised TF can be written as
$$G(s)=\frac{K}{s(s+4)(s+8)}$$
as the point is in the root locus the magnitude condition should satisfy that is

$$|G(S)|=1$$

from this 
\$K=|s(s+4)(s+8)|=|(-1.5+j1.5)(2.5+j1.5)(6.5+j1.5)|=41.25\$

that is option \$(C)\$

But the correct answer given as option \$(D)\$.also its a examination question so i am confused.

is there any mistake i am doing?

Comment: Do you have a typo in your equation for K? Did you mean to write "-2.5"?

Comment: @Tyler sorry.yes its just a typo,i fixed it....please check now